# WebRTC for iOS for VoIP communication

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, voip

Is there any WebRTC solution for iOS for free with easy setup?

I tried to use http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios because our web end is already done with its web api and I thought I may not have other way around for letting calls go between web and iOS too. But iOS API's setup is very tedious and time taking (The downloading of WebRTC checkout is taking like lives with no gain).

I searched around and found a few like tokBox and quickblox but they are not free.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at RestComm iOS SDK ? It supports WebRTC Audio only right now but we are working on adding video in the next few weeks. Also it uses SIP as a signalling protocol.

- https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-ios-sdk
  http://www.telestax.com/how-to-integrate-the-restcomm-ios-client-sdk-in-your-app/
  http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-client-ios-sdk-quick-start/

Comment: Thanks for reply, jeand. Actually I needed for video as well as audio calling. Still finding some way for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/oney/RCTWebRTCDemo .
This is a React Native WebRTC project which works on iOS and Android and also has a signaling server example (but you can also use the online version for quick tests!).

Answer (score 0):

Since the WebRTC requires DTLS-RTP, RTCP-FB, ICE and a lot of other newest standards, but the VoIP standards are old about 10+ years, therefore you need setup a gateway to convert the signaling and transcoding the RTP.

With the WebRTC Gateway, in the browser side, you can create the HTML5 application to connect to WebRTC gateway, the gateway will communicates with your PBX, and your iOS client connects to your PBX, then the call can be established between browser with iOS client app.